# PHP - Receive data from JSON with an URL

Tags: php, json, url

i have the url and need to get the value of 'tackle' from this json file.
http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/brown/zach

I tried this but its throwing errors -> undefined index

```
$url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/brown/zach";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo  $json_data["tackle"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API response contains an array (of games?), therefore you must select which (game?) to pull the tackle from. If you would just like to use the first (game?) the following code should suit your needs:

```
$url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/brown/zach";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo  $json_data[0]["defense"]["tackle"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/brown/zach";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($json_data as $item)
{
  echo $item["defence"]["tackle"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value tackle is within another object defence so you should try

```
echo  $json_data[0]["defence"]["tackle"];
```

Comment: solved it. echo  $json_data[0]["defense"]["tackle"];

Comment: ohh didn't notice the whole json was an array